# Нужна помощь с webSockets в Django

Tags: django, django-channels

Передо мной стоит задача сделать **Django приложение**, при помощи которого можно объединить несколько компьютеров в одну **светодиодную матрицу**(один монитор - один элемент матрицы, далее *пиксель*). То есть нужно чтобы при выборе **определённого пикселя** из списка открывалась страница, которая, например, берёт координаты этого пикселя(в моделях есть) и подставляет эти координаты в **двумерный массив** с цветами всех пикселей и отображает этот цвет на странице. Это нужно делать именно асинхронно так как **массив** с цветами **будет динамически меняться** в процессе работы приложения. Как это лучше сделать?
https://github.com/AlexeyReket/LCDfromDisplays
Пытался сам разобраться но всё забаговалось и вообще не работало. Вернул прошлую версию с гита и остановился на подключении вебсокетов. В Django новичок, не бейте сильно если вопрос глупый.

Comment: вопрос интересный и сложный, советую набрать 75 и обьяить конкурс на него